# Does Gedit have cool keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gedit

I have used Vim before and I love the keyboard shortcuts, but I hate having to copy and paste, so I am looking for a text editor that makes it easier. I have been trying Gedit. It's cool. But I really miss the being to create a new line, going to the end of the line, going to the beginning of the line, deleting a line with keyboard shortcuts.

I tried to look up "gedit keyboard shortcuts" but all it came up with was how to save a file. Basic things.

Comment: What about Vim's copy and paste did you find difficult? I find it really easy, so perhaps there is something in your Vim configuration that could be improved. For example, some GNU/Linux distributions include a vim that doesn't have the X11 and clipboard support necessary for proper copying and pasting in a terminal.

Answer (score 2):

See the Gedit [page](https://help.gnome.org/users/gedit/stable/gedit-shortcut-keys.html.en) for all the default hotkeys.

Answer (score 1):

[VIGedit](https://launchpad.net/vigedit) - might have to muck around with it a bit, but sounds like what you want.

also worth reading this "[ViGedit–Gedit’s Simplicity with Vi(m)’s Power](http://blog.tsmacdonald.com/archives/312)"

Answer (score 1):

I'm honestly not surprised you had problems with this considering the abusive upbringing you've had with Vi and Vim.

> shift + end, delete : delete line
>   shift + down, delete : delete line
>   ctrl + d : delete line
>
> home : beginning of line
>   end : end of line
>
> shift + tab : un-indent
>   tab : indent
>
> hightlight, shift + tab : un-indent
>   hightlight + tab : indent
>
> hightlight, ctrl + c : copy
>   hightlight, ctrl + x : cut
>   hightlight, ctrl + v : paste
>
> hightlight: secondary x11 clipboard copy
>   middle-click: secondary x11 clipboard paste

Those last two are X11-only features.

Comment: Note that the three "delete line" methods you mentioned are all different. Ctrl+D is the most useful.

Answer (score 1):

For sure, GNOME’s `gedit` wiki will direct you to a page with [“official” keyboard shortcuts](http://help.gnome.org/users/gedit/stable/gedit-shortcut-keys.html.en).

However, there is more to this story; `gedit` uses the [`GtkTextView`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTextView.html) widget to display and edit text. This means there are [more keyboard shortcuts](http://hamwaves.com/gedit/en/index.html) at play than those documented in the `gedit` wiki.

Here is [a longer list with **all** `gedit` shortcuts](http://hamwaves.com/gedit/en/index.html).